# How to understand type cast for pointer arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, casting

I am reading 《The C Programming Language》, second edition. I am a little confused about type cast for pointer arrays. The original full code can be found at [here](https://github.com/Heatwave/The-C-Programming-Language-2nd-Edition/blob/master/chapter-5-pointers-and-arrays/39.sort-with-r.c).

```
char *lineptr[100];
void qsort(void *lineptr[], int left, int right, int (*comp)(void *, void *));
main()
{
    //some code are omitted

    //usage 1, original code in the book
    qsort((void **) lineptr, 0, nlines-1, (int (*)(void*,void*))(numeric ?numcmp : strcmp));

    //usage 2, my understanding
    qsort((void *) lineptr, 0, nlines-1, (int (*)(void*,void*))(numeric ?numcmp : strcmp));
}
```

The author said "Any pointer can be cast to `void *` and back again without loss of information, so we can call `qsort` by casting arguments to `void *`." (chapter 5.11)

I have tested that both usage 1 and usage 2 can run successfully. I know usage 1 should be right, but how about usage 2 ? From my opinion, usage 2 should be right for casting `lineptr` to `void *`. What's the difference between `(void **) lineptr` and `(void *) lineptr` in this instance ?

Comment: That should not compile in C++. C and C++ are different languages. Please only tag the one you're using.

Comment: `void*` is a special case and is not related to `void**`

Comment: Your `qsort` function signature looks strange. Do you have your own implementation that happens to have the same name as the built-in [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert an array pointer `void* lineptr[]` to a `void**`, they are not compatible types. But `qsort` expects a pointer `void*` to the first element, so this isn't correct no matter.

Given `char *lineptr[100];`, then in C, simply pass the `lineptr` to `qsort` as-is, without casting.

Inside the callback, each `void*` will actually point at the address of a `char*`, so you might have to do something strange-looking like `char* ptr = *(char**)param;`.

In C++ you should be using `std::sort` instead.